# Netcat - Execute Command and send return

Tags: netcat

I'm trying to use netcat (the busybox version nc) to execute a command (devmem) on a remote machine and read the return on my local machine.

With

> nc -ll -p [port] [IP] -e /bin/cat

i was able to echo my commands (devmem 0x12345678).

I tried

> nc -ll -p [port] [IP] -e /bin/sh

, which didn't get me any response. (again sending "devmem 0x12345678" from my local machine)

Ultimately i want to be able to read/write memory on the remote machine from my local machine using nc and devmem.

Answer (score 2):

Solved my Problem by using this small script:

```
#!/bin/sh
while true
    do
        /sbin/devmem $(read str; echo $str)
done
```

and then starting netcat with:

```
nc -ll -p [port] -w 10 [IP] -e /scriptfile
```